# Get a combined query result set with a count of possible values from another query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario where I'd like to eliminate the number of query-of-queries I'm performing on a page. Let's say I have this, a result set called filtered_table:

```
SELECT 
    col_a
    ,col_b
    ,col_c
FROM
    table 
where 
    col_a = 1
```

Then I have a set of all possible results, were the query not filtered, distinct_col_a, distinct_col_b, distinct_col_c.

```
SELECT 
    distinct col_a
FROM
    table

SELECT 
    distinct col_b
FROM
    table

SELECT 
    distinct col_c
FROM
    table
```

Finally, for each value that distinct_col_a, distinct_col_b, distinct_col_c could contain, I perform a query of queries to get a count in filtered_table.

```
 (for each value in distinct_col_a)
    SELECT 
        count(col_a)
    FROM
        filtered_table
```

It's clunky and it's resource-heavy. I feel like there should be some way to do a rollup or something instead of the for each and get these numbers all in one go, but I can't wrap my head around it.

As an example:

`table`

```
col_a    |    col_b    |    col_c 
1        |    a        |    x
2        |    b        |    y
3        |    c        |    z
3        |    c        |    x
1        |    d        |    x
```

filtered_table, using `where col_a = 1`

```
   col_a    |    col_b    |    col_c 
    1        |    a        |    x
    1        |    d        |    x
```

The results I'm looking for:

```
 col_name| col_value| number results
   col_a  |   1      |    2
   col_a  |   2      |    0
   col_a  |   3      |    0
   col_b  |   a      |    1
   col_b  |   b      |    0
   col_b  |   c      |    0
   col_b  |   d      |    1
   col_c  |   x      |    2
   col_c  |   y      |    0
   col_c  |   z      |    0
```

Comment: I highly recommend making a specific example of what you want with some data.  E.g. this is the table, and this is the desired result.  Because it will give your question way more clarity and make it easier for us to help you. As it stands I have too many questions, such as what you are referring to with filtered_table.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a funky combination of `unpivot` and a separate aggregate to create these results in a fairly compact query:

```
declare @t table (col_a char(1), col_b char(1), col_c char(1))
insert into @t(col_a,col_b,col_c) values
('1','a','x'),
('2','b','y'),
('3','c','z'),
('3','c','x'),
('1','d','x')

select
    col_name, col_value, SUM(Cnt) as results_count
from
    (select *,CASE WHEN col_a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cnt from @t) t
        unpivot
    (col_value for col_name in (col_a, col_b, col_c)) p
group by col_name,col_value
```

Result:

```
col_name  col_value results_count
--------- --------- -------------
col_a     1         2
col_a     2         0
col_a     3         0
col_b     a         1
col_b     b         0
col_b     c         0
col_b     d         1
col_c     x         2
col_c     y         0
col_c     z         0
```

(Note - these results came out in the same order as your desired output. But there's currently no `ORDER BY` clause so that wasn't guaranteed)

Not that you apply your "`WHERE` clause" instead as a check within the `CASE` expression. If you can't see how this is working immediately, I'd suggest running

```
select
    *
from
    (select *,CASE WHEN col_a = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cnt from @t) t
        unpivot
    (col_value for col_name in (col_a, col_b, col_c)) p
```

first to see the effects that the `unpivot` produces.